# How to pass request string param using Retrofit for file Upload?

Tags: android, file-upload, parameters, retrofit

How to send the request string param using Retrofit. I have submitted the code below. Here how to add the string param and send to server.

AppConfig:

---

public class AppConfig {

```
public static String BASE_URL = "http://104.239.173.64/peoplecaddie-api";

public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}
```

ApiConfig:

```
public interface ApiConfig {

    @Multipart
    @POST("/general/Candidate/fileUpload")
    Call<ServerResponse> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map
    );
}
```

ServerResponse:

---

```
public class ServerResponse {

    // variable name should be same as in the json response from php
    @SerializedName("success")
    boolean success;
    @SerializedName("message")
    String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

}
```

### MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnUpload, btnPickImage, btnPickVideo;
    String mediaPath;
    ImageView imgView;
    String[] mediaColumns = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID};
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");

        btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
        btnPickImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_img);
        btnPickVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_vdo);
        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.preview);

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadFile();
            }
        });

        btnPickImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 0);
            }
        });

        // Video must be low in Memory or need to be compressed before uploading...
        btnPickVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
            }
        });

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                // Get the Image from data
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
                imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
                cursor.close();

            } // When an Video is picked
            else if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                // Get the Video from data
                Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                assert cursor != null;
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                // Set the Video Thumb in ImageView Previewing the Media
                imgView.setImageBitmap(getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(MainActivity.this, selectedVideo));
                cursor.close();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image/Video", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    // Providing Thumbnail For Selected Image
    public Bitmap getThumbnailPathForLocalFile(Activity context, Uri fileUri) {
        long fileId = getFileId(context, fileUri);
        return MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
                fileId, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
    }

    // Getting Selected File ID
    public long getFileId(Activity context, Uri fileUri) {
        Cursor cursor = context.managedQuery(fileUri, mediaColumns, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            return cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // Uploading Image/Video
    private void uploadFile() {
        progressDialog.show();

        // Map is used to multipart the file using okhttp3.RequestBody
        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        File file = new File(mediaPath);
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
        map.put("fileContent0\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);

       ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
        Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload(token, map);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
                if (serverResponse != null) {
                    if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                        Log.e("Response", serverResponse.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Response", serverResponse.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Throwable", t.toString());
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client2.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.delaroystudios.androidupload/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client2, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.delaroystudios.androidupload/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client2, viewAction);
        client2.disconnect();
    }
}
```

In the above example code just passed the token and File with the help of request Body.

- How to send request string param with above code.

that is How to send Below  login_params details as a request param using retrofit. when i tried i got 
/Throwable: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $ . this exception.

```
  HashMap<String, String> login_params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        login_params.put("fileCount", "1");
        login_params.put("id","1743");
        login_params.put("fileType", "SAMPLE");
        login_params.put("platform", "Android");
        login_params.put("externalID", "portpolio");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use @PartMap annotation to pass parameters along with File request. PartMap is a Map of "Key" and RequestBody. So first, you have to create RequestBody object of the parameter that you want to pass and then create Map object of it and pass it as argument.

For example your method in api interface would be,

```
@Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadFileWithPartMap(
            @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

and request would be,

```
MultipartBody.Part body = prepareFilePart("photo", fileUri);

// create a map of data to pass along
RequestBody token= RequestBody.create(
        MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), "token_string");
HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();  
map.put("token", token);  

-----------------

private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {  
    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

and finally the calling method would be,

```
// finally, execute the request
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.uploadFileWithPartMap(map, body);  
call.enqueue(...);
```

I hope this will help you and for detailed reference please check this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap

Comment: Thanks for your reply . here prepareFilePart("photo", fileUri);
means what? getting file uri method? Could you please let me know that method code? @srushti

Comment: @karthik it creates MultipartBody object from file data. I have updated my answer, please check it out.

Comment: finally work good. I used RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
        Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("fileContent0\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestFile); it works fine

Comment: Here upload file method I can track the response using. This works fine.using System.out.println("Rrespppppp--->"+response.body().string());But while try to convert the JSON Object it will not work the error code is below. And please let me know how do i parse and get the success and failure response value using this code.      @Srushti

Comment: If your response **response.body().string()‌** is giving right output, then there might be some issue with parsing response. Make sure that the model you are using is correct in terms of structure as well as properties/variables.

Comment: And if there is some problem in response, you can check it using **response.errorBody().string()**